# How to send an http request to google tagmanager server side

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to migrate our track system to use google tagmanager server side. Instead to send requests from backend directly to other tracks I want to use GTM as a proxy. So I've created a new container called "back":
[image: the back container]

then I've activated the google cloud hosting for that container. They gave-me an default url: https://gtm-foo-bar.uc.r.appspot.com, an projectId: gtm-foo-bar and a container configuration: dasdfasd|asdfsdfdf. I'm supposing that container configuration works like a API key (but I didn't find anything about that).

Then I've created the following variables:
[image: variables]

Also, I've created a login trigger:
[image: login trigger image]

That fires the Iterable tag:
[image]

Also, I've create a "Receive Event" client that points to route /event:
[image: receive event cliend]

On postman, I'm trying to send request to https://gtm-foo-bar.uc.r.appspot.com/event
[image: postman image]

When I try to make this request, the server answer with 400. So, What should I do to send this request to the GTM server side?

Comment: http 400 is a sign that no client is claiming your request. If you use the measurement protocol client, you have to send a request that is formatted according to the measurement protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a Client that will receive your "Custom" requests.

For example, you can use this one https://github.com/stape-io/data-client
Or here is a post on how to do the very similar task with an explanation of the setup process https://stape.io/send-data-from-crm-to-facebook-conversion-api-using-webhooks/

Comment: I've followed the instructions of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bg8ns8nPF8I 

I found it in this article: https://stape.io/sending-data-from-google-tag-manager-web-container-to-the-server-container/

It was located on the first link that you sent me. So It solved my problem. Thanks